# Tree traversing optimisation

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I have a simple tree data structure in JavaScript using nested objects like,

```
class Node {
    name: "",
    children: [
       ...Node
    ]
}

rootNode=[Node, Node, Node...]
```

Now,

I traverse tree and find all nodes matching predicates like,

```
 let result =[];
 let allNodes =[];
 if isArray(rootNode) {
     rootNode.each(x=>{
         allNodes.push(x)
     });
 } else {
     allNodes.push(rootNode);
 }

while (allNodes.length) {
    let currentNode = allNodes.shift();
    if (predicate(currentNode) {
          result.push(currentNode);
    }
    if (currentNode.children.length) {

         allNodes.push(addAllChild(currentNode.children))
     }

 }
```

Is there any effective way of doing above?

Comment: try [tree-node-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-node-utils). I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it recursively, since you do not need to do it in a certain order.  Here, you do not have the overhead of storing all the node references in allNodes, and also due to tail call optimization, this code will probably run faster than iterative code:

```
var result = [];
function traverse(curr)  {
   if(predicate(curr)) {
      result.push(curr);
   }
   for(var i=0; i < curr.children.length; i++) {
      traverse(curr.children[i]);
   }
}
//Iterate through the array of root nodes
for(var j=0;j < allNodes.length; j++) {
   traverse(allNodes[j]);
}
```